# Solution to perspectivicly warp the whole screen?

Tags: projector

Is there a way to perspectively warp the whole screen, so i can
correct a image which is displayed on a projection screen from a strange angle?

Background is, we have a play and i would like to project background screens. Because i want to use a variety of Media Types and also would like to remote control the whole thing, the easiest way would be to simply warp the whole screen instead of using projection mapping or something.

To be clear, there is just one rectangular surface i need to transform the image on.

Comment: Some projectors do have setting so this can be adjusted - what projector are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, blame me but I'm confused. How exactly is this question about Ubuntu?

Comment: I want to do it on Ubuntu and i want to do it on a pretty low level, meaning that the whole screen gets bend. (I didn`t write explicit that this is about a Ubuntu System, you are right)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `xrandr` tool and its `--transform` option to which you can pass a 3x3 transformation matrix.

Unfortunately I don't know any GUI to compute the transformation matrix.
But several open sources project have tool to do that (OpenCV, openFrameworks...) from 2 set of 4 corners.